# Qt::Tool appear too fast when parent restored

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface

I have a qt application, window with several child widgets that are Qt::Tool windows.

When I minimize window and then restore on windows 7 child widgets appear immediately, but parent window not because of animation.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior and make child windows appear after main window?

Comment: This behaviour is dependent on the window manager. It would be best not to try and change it. Why does a short delay really matter anyway?

Comment: because process of restoring looks ugly that way, I want application to behave as nice as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you hide the tool windows while the main window is restoring? You can use this piece of code and adapt it to your needs:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent( QEvent* e )
{
  if ( e->type() == QEvent::WindowStateChange )
  {
    QWindowStateChangeEvent* event = 
        static_cast< QWindowStateChangeEvent* >( e );
    if ( event->oldState() & Qt::WindowMinimized ) {
      qDebug() << "The Window has been restored!";
    }
    else if ( (event->oldState() == Qt::WindowNoState) && 
              (this->windowState() == Qt::WindowMaximized) ) {
      qDebug() << "the window has been Maximized!";
    }
  }
}
```

For example, you can start a timer for a certain amount of time, and have the slot connected to your child tool windows, making them appear as you wish.

You can also play with transparency in the child tool windows, and emulate the main window effects.

As I recall, something like this will do:

```
setStyleSheet("background:transparent;");
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: timer and custom transparency is a last resort to solve that problem, I'd even prefer some winapi message catching to this, since this would work better and easier to isolate from crossplatform code.

Comment: I have solved it using delay to show widget, seems that is really the only option.